# How to get the column counts of StackedHeaders?

Tags: c#, winforms, draggable

In my project, I have checked with many test cases and in one test case, I have dragged the stacked column header, I need to get the column counts belongs to that StackedHeader because I have to do some customization with their column index. Please anyone suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define your code like:

```
private int RecursiveIteration(GridFieldCollection field)  {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < field.Count ; i++)
    {
        if (field[i].GetType() == typeof(GroupField))
        {
            count += RecursiveIteration((field[i] as GroupField).Columns);
        }
        count++;
}

    return count;  }
```

To get total count: `int colCount = RecursiveIteration(WebDataGrid1.Columns);`